# Unable to stop a while loop with button

Tags: matlab, while-loop, interrupt

I'm trying to create a GUI-controlled program intended to process a live-stream acquired from a microscope-camera, it's supposed to recognize the shape of user-defined objects in the stream, calculate their edges and center and overlay those onto the stream, in effect tracking the object. This already works quite well and I'd like to continue, but I'm having a problem where I'm just unable to interrupt the while-loop that's doing the frame processing. I'd like to be able to do that because there may be good reasons to abort a tracking process much later. The idea was to just have a push button that changes a flag that is checked on every iteration of the loop to false and be done with it, only that it doesn't work.

Searching the net I found that it seems to be a callback-queue related issue. The push of the button that is used to alter the break-flag is never registered as long as the loop is running, which I tested by inserting a break point in its callback, which is never triggered even if the button is clicked. On several occasions solutions suggested to use `drawnow` to temporarily stop the loop and process any queued callbacks, but that just doesn't seem to do anything. I also checked whether the `Interruptible` and `BusyAction` properties of the button and the image (which needs to be clicked on to start the tracking) are set to `On` and `queue` respectively. They are, but the fact remains that I can't interrupt that loop.

As stated above, the tracking commences when the `livestream` in an axes object is clicked. the code for that is as follows:

```
function ImageClickCallback(hObject, eventData, handles)

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %--------- Selection of object to monitor --------%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% get handle to the axes object the stream is displayed in
axesHandle  = get(hObject,'Parent');

% get coordinates of mouseclick and store them in a struct
coordinates = get(axesHandle,'CurrentPoint'); 
coordinates = coordinates(1,1:2);

% save those coordinates in the figure's appdata for further usage
setappdata(handles.figure1,'ccoordx',coordinates(1)); 
setappdata(handles.figure1,'ccoordy',coordinates(2)); 

% overlay marker onto video stream
hold on
scatter(coordinates(1),coordinates(2),400,'r','x', 'LineWidth', 2 );
hold off

% Display x and y values in textboxes
set(handles.text2, 'String', getappdata(handles.figure1, 'ccoordx'));
set(handles.text3, 'String', getappdata(handles.figure1, 'ccoordy'));

% enable tracking state
setappdata(handles.figure1, 'tracker', 1);
drawnow

set(findobj(gca,'BusyAction', 'cancel'), 'Interruptible', 'On');
tracker=getappdata(handles.figure1, 'tracker');
stream=getappdata(handles.figure1, 'stream');

while tracker == 1

       % get currently displayed frame and convert to grayscale

        singleframe=getsnapshot(stream);

        % run the ObjectFinder and save the result, objectfinder is a self-programmed function thats doing the object-recognition
        [alphamask, center, errorcode] = objectFinder(singleframe, getappdata(handles.figure1, 'ccoordx'), getappdata(handles.figure1,'ccoordy'), handles);

        % abort if user clicked a non-object area
        if errorcode == 2
           msgbox('Not a valid object.');
           return
        end

        % add alphamask to green picture to create overlay on axes1
        hold on
        set(findobj(gca,'BusyAction', 'cancel'), 'AlphaData', alphamask);
        hold off

        % update x and y coordinates of chosen object to its current
        % center of mass
        setappdata(handles.figure1,'ccoordx',center(1,1)); 
        setappdata(handles.figure1,'ccoordy',center(1,2)); 

        % make center of mass visible
        set(findobj(gca,'Type','scatter'), 'XData', center(1,1));
        set(findobj(gca,'Type','scatter'), 'YData', center(1,2));
        flushdata(stream);
        set(findobj(gca,'BusyAction', 'cancel'), 'Interruptible', 'On');

        % this is where the condition is checked
        tracker=getappdata(handles.figure1, 'tracker');

        drawnow

end

% this part is supposed to delete the overlay when the loop is terminated 
% by the button push    

hold on
delete(findobj(gca,'Type', 'Scatter'));
set(findobj(gca,'BusyAction', 'cancel'), 'AlphaData', 0);
hold off
drawnow
```

The `setappdata` and `getappdata` functions are used to make several pieces of data available to the whole program, they are there for a reason. The declaring of the `videoObject`, the initialization of the GUI and so on take place in the `trackerGUI_OpeningFcn`, which I can of course post as well if asked.

The code for the button I'm trying to use for the loop-termination is as follows

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% disable tracking state
setappdata(handles.figure1, 'tracker', 0);
guidata(hObject, handles);
drawnow
```

As I said, the tracking works fine (albeit only at about 2 frames/sec, which could be a bit higher), I just can't interrupt it. Interestingly, something else also doesn't quite work, probably for the same reasons: I have a slider in my GUI that sets a `fudgefactor` to be used in the pattern recognition function. If I change it while the tracking is active, the altered `fudgefactor` effect can be seen in the stream/overlay immediately, but the text-field that is supposed to show the currently selected factor isn't updated as long as the loop is running. If it's not, it's immediately updated.

Comment: Try using a toggle button and have your while loop check the state of the toggle to decide whether or not to break out of the loop.

Comment: 1. Try to replace `drawnow` with `pause(0.001)`. 2. Remove the while loop, and verify `pushbutton1_Callback` is executed when button is pressed. 3. What version of Matlab and OS are you using?

Comment: you may use multi-thread code to do several jobs in parallel(so when your loop is running other parts of your gui is working). create a global variable and use it as flag in your while loop, then create another thread for your gui and try to set the flag with a button

Comment: @Rotem I'm using Windows 10 and Matlab r2016a. I don't have to access to Matlab and my program atm, but I will try to implement those changes on monday. Also daren i don't really know how to do what you suggested - how do I explicitly run things in parallel? If the Parallel Processing Toolbox is required for that: I dont have it.

Answer (score -1):

I did not read the question fully the first time. Also, I tried to comment but I don't have the reputation.

Why don't you try initializing the tracker in handles with

```
handles.tracker = 1;
```

in your gui loading code, and then loop using

```
while handles.tracker
```

In the button to stop tracking, have your callback execute `handles.tracker = 0;`

Comment: I will try that on monday, but is there a reason handles.tracker should work while doing the same with set/getappdata(handles.figure1 'tracker') doesnt? I figured that's the same, only that the flag is saved in the handles and the figure respectively. Am I missing something?